# can't freeze db2 python binding into executable

Tags: python, compilation, db2, pyinstaller

I'm using a Python program with PyQt based GUI, to connect to a database, everyting worked good while it's python script, but got problem while trying to compile it

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/

https://pypi.org/project/ibm_db/

such DB2 Python binding / connector got .dll / .pyd files, that failed to link

code piece

```
try:
    import ibm_db
    import ibm_db_dbi
    logger.info("module loaded")
    logger.info("ibm_db loaded from %s" % ibm_db.__file__)
    logger.info("ibm_db_dbi loaded from %s" % ibm_db_dbi.__file__)
except:
    logger.warn("failed to load db2 related modules")
    logger.warn(traceback.format_exc())

try:
    logger.info("environment variable are: %s" % str(os.environ))
except:
    logger.warn(traceback.format_exc())
```

when execute as script

```
2019-03-06 14:22:39,032 | INFO: hello
D: dynamic load ibm_db from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll
2019-03-06 14:22:39,825 | INFO: module loaded
2019-03-06 14:22:39,825 | INFO: ibm_db loaded from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll
2019-03-06 14:22:39,825 | INFO: ibm_db_dbi loaded from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.pyc
2019-03-06 14:22:39,825 | INFO: connecting ["DATABASE=testdb;HOSTNAME=172.25.31.153;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db2inst1;PWD=password;", "", ""]
2019-03-06 14:22:40,776 | INFO: query SELECT * from SYSIBM.TABLES FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
2019-03-06 14:22:40,776 | INFO: {'TABLE_TYPE': u'BASE TABLE', 'TABLE_SCHEMA': u'SYSIBM  ', 'IS_INSERTABLE_INTO': u'YES', 'USER_DEFINED_TYPE_SCHEMA': None, 'TABLE_NAME':     u'SYSTABLES', 'USER_DEFINED_TYPE_CATALOG': None, 'SELF_REFERENCING_COLUMN_NAME': None, 'TABLE_CATALOG': u'TESTDB', 'USER_DEFINED_TYPE_NAME': None, 'REFERENCE_GENERATION': None}
```

when compiled using pyinstaller

```
C:\Users\jack.wu>dist\test_db2\test_db2.exe
2019-03-06 14:23:17,769 | INFO: hello
D: dynamic load ibm_db from C:\Users\jack.wu\dist\test_db2\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll
2019-03-06 14:23:17,770 | WARNING: failed to load db2 related modules
2019-03-06 14:23:17,778 | WARNING: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_db2.py", line 27, in <module>
    import ibm_db
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 11, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried few parameters like `--add-binary` or `--hidden-import` , both did not work, any idea / clue ？

**[update 20190307]** this problem mostly **disappeard** after run `python setup.py install` of ibm_db, instead of just extract the folder statically and put it at same folder. the discussion happened at latter situation, lower priority, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is the file present at C:\Users\jack.wu\dist\test_db2\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll ?

Comment: Have you tried running pyinstaller with the --clean option ?

Comment: @mao the dll file is prepared, in all kinds of folder layouts, still not good, and my colleague came up with a solution

Comment: @mao the "good practise" my colleague did is, install the ibm_db properlly, with "python setup.py install" which seems regist dll and inject site-packages library, then the compile worked smooth, as long as we put the binary there, only .dll required

Comment: @mao the "bad practise" i did, is trying to hack the ibm_db python wrapper, since originally i don't have permission to do such installation / write system folder, even with this, seems the "path to find dll" is freezed permernantly, mostly due to there are some imp.load_dynamic within the wrapper, and pyinstaller had not parsed it well, and i did not explictly fill it correct

Comment: , pyinstaller also works with ibm_db if you use the --add-binary option to cause the dll to be copied into the bundle in the ibm_db_dlls directory.